# Acer TimelineX 5830TG internal microphone not working

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, pulseaudio, microphone

Problem: In Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04, if you try to use internal mic, it gets a lot of static and is almost impossible to hear on the other side because of extremely low sound (voip calls).

Recorder might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me, was to install "pavucontrol", Pulse Audio Volume Control.

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

After installation, go to Input Devices, and press the Lock icon that locks channel level together. Then, I set Right to 50% and left to 25%, which in my case gave me a very clear sound. I tested it with my desktop PC in Skype and Hangouts.

[image]

The problem is called "Inverted mic", and seems that having 2 channels at the same level makes them cancel out each other [Need quote here lol]

I also disabled the recording option called "Monitor", but this wasn't required.

There is another tab, which shows programs currently USING the recording device, you may have to edit settings there too if the first step doesn't work good.

Another thing I noticed is that Google Hangouts was modifying the settings, so I had to modify its settings:

```
cd ~/.config/google-googletalkplugin    # get to google chat's directory
cp -p options options.bak        # make a backup before changing stuff !
gedit options                # edit the config file
```

now change one of the lines so that it reads as follows:

```
audio-flags=1
```

Source for the Hangouts Problem: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/n1cpJq1mC8U